# Using the same object to run multiple LINQs

Tags: c#, linq

**UPDATED**

I have been trying to run multiple `LINQ`s off of one object.

```
TestObject myObject = entities.TestObject.FirstOrDefault(t => t.number == foo.number && t.deleted == "N")

myObject = entities.TestObject.FirstOrDefault(t => t.number == foo.number && t.deleted == "N")

myObject = entities.TestObject.FirstOrDefault(t => t.number == fooTest.number && t.deleted == "N")

myObject = entities.TestObject.FirstOrDefault(t => (t.number == fooTestTwo.number || t.anotherNumber == fooTestTwo.number) && t.deleted == "N")
```

Now if I use `myObject` for multiple `LINQ`s it seems that after the third `LINQ` its not querying properly unless I set it back to `null`.

```
myObject = null;
```

In the fourth `LINQ` the OR statement isn't working correctly and only fires on the first condition.

Should I be creating multiple object for the different queries or is setting the object back to null a better way to handle this?

Comment: What is the error message? By doing what process you came with this issue? Add more details please.

Comment: Can you show code which actually demonstrates the problem?  Currently you have one line of code which you claim works.  Then you allude to some problem in some other code that you're not showing.  We can't really help with that.  If you're just asking whether or not you can assign a value to a variable, then yes, yes you should be able to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting myObject with fundamentally different Linq expressions then the thing that myObject represents will keep changing and this can be confusing/lead to bugs. You should create a new objects for each of your linq expressions and name them so that their name represents what they are e.g. myMostRecentObject, myMostExpensiveObject etc...